# add references or not in all my tables?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have many tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `name` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES users (`id`),
  `user2` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES users (`id`),
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I'd like to know if this `references users` is a good choice of I should leave it blank to faster performance and improvement?

Comment: It will automatically detect if you try to create a `name` where the `user` and `user2` columns don't refer to existing users.

Comment: @Barmar is it a good practise or can I remove it? thanks again.

Comment: It's a good idea if you want the database to automatically detect application errors.

Comment: Foreign key constraints are generally a good practice; the only time they really need/should be dropped is in high transaction rate or extremely time sensitive systems where the speed of an insert is really really important. (and even if all code checks first and can be trusted, it makes the database more self-documenting.)

Comment: There's overhead, so you have to decide whether it's worth it.

Comment: Questions about "good practice" are highly opinionated, and not appropriate for SO.

Comment: thank you very much tho, friends! Barmar and @Uueerdo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using foreign keys has little to do with performance. In fact, it can *add* a little bit of overhead, because any insert or update to your table needs to verify that the value exists in the referenced table. But in practice, this isn't much more overhead than updating an index.

The reason to use foreign keys is not performance, it's for ensuring data integrity. Without a foreign key, any update to your database might delete a parent row in `users` even if there are rows in `name` that reference it. Without the foreign key constraint, it's only your coding habits that keep the data intact. With a foreign key constraint, a delete of a row in `users` will return an error if there are other rows depending on it.

This might sound like it's a good idea, but there are different opinions. The constraint may restrict some work that you need to do. I've talked to developers who find constraints hinder them when they need to clean up malformed data, for example. It's also true that locking behavior may surprise you: for example if you update a dependent row in `name` will create a lock on the row it references in `users`.

```
/* this also implicitly puts a shared lock on `users` where id = 1234 */ 
UPDATE name SET ... WHERE user = 1234;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL's InnoDB storage engine does not support the syntax you show, where you declare the `REFERENCES` clause in each column definition. Despite this being standard SQL, it is not recognized in MySQL.

You'll find that defining foreign keys this way is accepted without error, but it ignores the request silently, and doesn't implement the constraint.

InnoDB supports only the syntax for table-level foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE `name` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user2` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES users (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user2`) REFERENCES users (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The end result is the same, in the way the data is stored and the performance implications. The only difference is in the syntax used to define foreign key constraints.